# Contain and Animate the content of a .TXT called via AJAX in a DIV

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, animation, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to accomplish a purely visual effect, but my limited knowledge of AJAX is holding me back - so after 3 hours of unsuccessful googling, I figured I'd ask the experts!

I have an HTML page (built on Bootstrap). I have a div (one-quarter of the page, full height) I want to display line after line of scrolling text. Ideally, I'd be able to style the content via CSS.

I am able to successfully call the file and it displays in the DIV with this:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
      <div id="code"></div>
 </div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.ajax({
    url : "code.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
        jQuery("#code").html(data);
    }
});});
```

That successfully takes the content of "code.txt" and displays it in the rough area of the DIV. However, the content is all displayed all at once, and it overflows the boundaries of the div.

How do I go about

1. Containing the called file within the bounds of my DIV
2. Display the called file character by character (as though it were simply being typed very quickly)

I am using XAMPP to view the page as localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple function to show text letter by letter. Call the function on AJAX success. Apply some css on `div` to adjust content.

```js
var str = "your context or what you get from ajax success"
TextLetterByLetter("#code", str, 0, 100);

function TextLetterByLetter(target, message, index, interval) {
  if (index < message.length) {
    $(target).append(message[index++]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      TextLetterByLetter(target, message, index, interval);
    }, interval);
  } else {
    index = 0;
    $(target).html('');
    TextLetterByLetter(target, message, index, interval);
  }
}
```

```css
#code{
    width:200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block">
  <div id="code"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, and is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

And I see how I can easily style the actual div directly in CSS. I was missing the "word-wrap: break-word" (though I knew that was important, somehow).

Your help is truly appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help :)